# Compiler Directives is not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I write a condition using compiler directive, but it's not working

Please look at the image below, the configuration QA specific code is not active.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional compilation doesn't work with project configuration names.

Add a **Conditional compilation symbol** `QA` under **Build** in the Visual Studio Project Properties.